# "webpack config" - modify assets path of the generated html file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

When we build the react app using `react-scripts build`, the relative paths for the created js/css are like: **/static/js/main.b8ba68fa.js** and so on.

Generated **index.html**:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css" />
  <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.b8ba68fa.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

The **index.html** I need:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="icon" href="{{DOMAIN}}/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="{{DOMAIN}}/manifest.json" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{DOMAIN}}/fonts/fonts.css" />
  <script defer="defer" src="{{DOMAIN}}/static/js/main.b8ba68fa.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

What I need is that all the paths of the generated index.html have this string **{{DOMAIN}}** prepended to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials, I discovered that:
The `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin which generates the **index.html** file, uses the `webpackConfig.output.publicPath` (the webpack config object) to prepend to all the paths.

I modified the `webpack.config.js` to this:

```
{
  output: {
    ...
    // publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath (how it was)
    publicPath: isEnvProduction ? '{{DOMAIN}}' : paths.publicUrlOrPath,  
    ...
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to modify webpack configuration without ejecting the CRA app. But once you do you'll be able to modify the build output folder for JS and CSS in webpack.

For more info about ejecting
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/cra-template/template/README.md#npm-run-eject

Comment: I thought that was the case. I checked the `webpack.config.js` file inside `@node-modules/react-scripts` and there was this property `filename: isEnvProduction ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js' : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',`. This is the thing I have to modify I guess.

Comment: Yes...but you'll have to eject the CRA first.

Comment: I was searching and i hit upon `react-app-rewired`. It says it can modify the webpack config without having to eject (basically it is a config override). I don't know if it's any good, but will try this.

Comment: I would personally recommend building a fresh webpack config with all the necessary customizations because it is pretty straight forward and well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I am aware of that, but as you can guess I was asking for a quick solution because: 1) for now this is the only customization I need and 2) I haven't learned Webpack yet :P

Comment: Webpack is probably the easiest to learn and even more easy to forget kind of a library. You understand and learn stuff at the beginning of a project and will not look at it again until you begin a new project and then you learn it all over again. Basically its the story of my life.

Comment: It all comes with experience. For example, just by intuition I literally discovered it in a matter of minutes the `fileName` in the config file. I hope I don't forget it in the near future :P

Comment: Good luck with that and happy to help!